# Assign a static IP address using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, mac-address, static-ip-address

I am a beginner in PowerShell. I am trying to get the two lines of code below that I found here on another answer to run in PowerShell 5.

```
$netAdapter = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where {$_.MACAddress -eq '0F:98:90:D6:42:92'}
$netAdapter.EnableStatic("192.168.1.1", "255.255.255.0")
```

Is there additional code required for this to properly execute?

I get the error message "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." when I try to use it. I replaced the MAC address and IP address with the data for my device and network. I thought that maybe the second command returns a value, but I couldn't figure out the data type if that is the problem.

In the past I have used Bootp for IP address assignments where a non-PC device only has a MAC address with no valid IP address. Bootp isn't showing the broadcast for my device but I can see it in WireShark.

Comment: Did you check what the content of $netAdapter is? What question is that code from? If you are on PS5 you should be able to use [`Get-NetAdapter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapter?view=windowsserver2019-ps) and [`Set-NetIPAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/set-netipaddress?view=windowsserver2019-ps) which should be a lot easier to use.

Comment: Sounds like you're getting no result in line one.  Otherwise it seems like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say much about your code snippet, except that I personally would avoid the "diversions" via Get-WmiObject whenever possible. In this case, that is also easily possible.

This code:

```
$netAdapter = Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.MacAddress -eq '0F:98:90:D6:42:92'}
New-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceIndex $netAdapter.ifIndex -IPAddress 192.168.1.1 -PrefixLength 24
```

Is 100% PowerShell without Wmi and should work without problems. (Admin rights are required, this could already be the problem with your code).

Comment: This can be shortened to just one line by piping to the `New-NetIPAddress` cmdlet but at least I'm getting an error if DHCP is still enabled. Which can be disabled using `Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.MacAddress -eq '0F:98:90:D6:42:92'} | Set-NetIPInterface -Dhcp disabled -PolicyStore activestore`. A reboot might be required.

Answer (score 0):

Before set the IP address to the interface, you must know the properties of the interface. To know the interface properties use the below command.

```
Get-NetIPAddress
```

It will show the output as

[image: interface properties]

If you have multiple interfaces you will get the list of interface properties.

From the properties, you can note down the interface index value. then you can use the below command to set the IP address.

If you are setting the IP address first time the use command as

```
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.10.100 -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 192.168.10.1 -InterfaceIndex 4
```

To modify the existing static IP address use below command

```
Set-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.10.100 -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 192.168.10.1 -InterfaceIndex 4
```

To Set the Primary DNS & Secondary DNS use below command

```
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 4 -ServerAddresses ('4.2.2.2','8.8.8.8')
```

To get the updated output for IP address and DNS use below command

```
Get-DnsClientServerAddress
Get-NetIPAddress
```

Answer (score -1):

Another approach, while strictly not utilizing PowerShell directly, is to use good old netsh. At least I find it much easier to memorize, than the weird PowerShell commands:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="INTERFACE NAME" static IP_ADDRESS SUBNET_MASK GATEWAY
```

To set it back to automatic configuration via DHCP use.

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="INTERFACE NAME" source=dhcp
```