# Changing the ip and mask of a network adapter in a virtual machine with PowerShell 7

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, uac

I have tried first with the various options offered by the GET-VM module to get the ip and mask of each of the adapters but none of them return this information. Then, I tried to send a script to the other machine and launch the development from there, which would work if I didn't have to raise permissions.

Would you know how to get the complete information of the adapters and change both the ip and the mask?
Thanks!

```
Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList "-noexit","-File", "file url" -verb runas -Wait
Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList "-noexit","-File", "file url" -cred credentials-Wait
```

and another function to elevate permissions that doesn't let me either.

I always get the "Exception calling "Start" with "1" argument(s): "This operation requires an interactive window station" window.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. The question and code snippet seem unrelated

Comment: I need to get the ip's of the different network adapters and be able to change both the ip and the adapter mask. All this to a virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

The IP address is configured on the OS inside the VM. You need to query the OS directly. For windows you can use the shells Netsh command or for pure powershell use Get-NetIPAdress, New-NetIPAddress and Set-NetIPAddress.

Examples:
netsh int ip set address "local area connection" static 192.168.20.50 255.255.255.0 192.168.20.254 1

Set-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.20.500 -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 192.168.20.1 -InterfaceIndex 1

More examples here:
[Assign a static IP address using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749788/assign-a-static-ip-address-using-powershell)

Comment: but to launch those commands in the vm I have to shell or powershell as administrator. I know the commands to launch, the problem is that the .exe do not open as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess by your other comments, could it be that you have trouble opening an interactive shell that runs both elevated **and** under a different user?

**Start-Process** sadly does not allow you to specify both **-Verb RunAs** and **-Credential** at the same time, so we need a workaroud.

One way to accomplish that would be to use **runas**. One caveat is that you need to type the password in the prompt, since there is no password parameter.

```
runas /u:DOMAIN\USER "powershell.exe -Command Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs"
```

On the other hand, the error message...

> Exception calling "Start" with "1" argument(s): "This operation requires an interactive window station"

... indicates that you issue the command remotely (i.e. via **Invoke-Command**). Since with remote commands you have no interactive session, no user interface to interact with, that operation fails.

When you call a system remotely, you have some options

1. Run **Invoke-Command** in a powershell that already runs as the desired user
2. Pass the credentials of the desired user explicitly in **Invoke-Command**. If the user has admin rights on the target machine, this remote session will run elevated automatically by design. You do not need to elevate manually. In fact it's not even possible to run with restricted permissions remotely

   ```
   Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'MyVM' -Credential (Get-Credential) -ScriptBlock {...}
   ```

Comment: How would I enter the password through the invoke? of course if it were on the machine itself it would be easier, but it would be through a vm

Comment: if I log in manually and run powershell as admin with the user it lets me, but for the invoke it returns this: Remove-NetIPAddress : Access is denied. with the same user